# I need to find the sum of odd numbers in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, average

I need to find the sum and count of odd numbers in a file using python but I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

code:

```py
file = open("numbers.txt", "r")
file_contents = file.readlines()

for i in file_contents:
    i = i.strip('\n')
    print(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        odd_sum += int(i)
        odd_count += 1
    print(odd_sum)
```

Comment: You are trying to find a modulo of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the `i` in this line to `int`:

```
 if int(i) % 2 == 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

i is a string so you cant calculate a modulo. Try to do your casting to `int()` in line 5:

```
i = int(i.strip('\n'))
```

instead of line 8

```
odd_sum += int(i)
```

If you want to calculate the sum of all odd numbers you can also do:

```
odd_sum = sum(ii for i in file_contents if (ii := int(i.strip('\n'))) % 2 == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from applying `%` to a string, since the line hasn't been converted to a number yet.  This is treated as old-style string formatting, e.g.

```
>>> 'time %d hours' % 2     # insert 2 into the format string
'time 2 hours'
>>> 'time hours' % 2        # no insertion point gives the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

So the code is doing the following:

```
>>> '2' % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

There were a number of errors in the code provided as well.  Below are fixes and suggestions:

```py
odd_sum = 0     # initialize variables
odd_count = 0
with open("numbers.txt") as file:  # with closes file when block exits
    for line in file:   # no need for .readlines(), iterate file directly
        num = int(line) # use better variable names, convert the line.
        print(num)      # no need for .strip('\n') as int() ignores whitespace
        if num % 2:  # implied non-zero is True, meaning odd (==0 checked even)
            odd_sum += num
            odd_count += 1
    print(f'{odd_count=} {odd_sum=}') # f-strings for nice formatting
```

Output given a file with 1-5 lines.

```
1
2
3
4
5
odd_count=3 odd_sum=9
```